# How to close all inherited handles from .NET

Tags: c#, .net, process, handle

I have a .NET process which is launching another daemon-like .NET process via the `Process` class. Because `Process` leverages handle inheritance (https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/306), it seems like my daemon process will prevent handles owned by the parent from being cleaned up.

Therefore, I'd like to have the child process start by closing all handles it inherited from its parent (except for the standard IO streams). Is there a .NET API that would allow me to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to worry about it too much.  Reading the github reference you linked and this article:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683463(v=vs.85).aspx

I don't think there is an issue unless you are explicitly creating file handles, etc. in the parent process that are marked as inheritable.

Another option would be to use PInvoke to manually call CreateProcess with InheritHandles set to false.

https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/CreateProcess.html